# .NET Charts show duplicate Y-values

Tags: .net, charts

I am using `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` for a visualization tool. Unfortunately, I cant post images so [sharing from my OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FAE9CB8C77D184B9!218561&authkey=!AK69G_WuV9iF8QE&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng). It happens only when lot of data points are all within a small Y-range. In this case values on Y-axis are seconds and they are all between 1.2 secs to 1.8 secs. Is there a way to display this in a better way?

All I want do is to create a series, add a `ChartArea` to it and then add individual datapoints.

Comment: Can you post the sample data? Which you are passing to the chart?